# How to return several results in a only one GraphQL request?

Tags: graphql, grandstack

I have a GRANDstack app.

For this app I have a Cypher request in Neo4j like this:

```
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)
WITH c
ORDER BY c.cluster_score DESC
LIMIT 5
MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_CLUSTER]-(a:ARTICLE)
WITH c,a
ORDER BY a.article_score  DESC
RETURN c, collect(a)[..5] as articles
```

It returns the best articles in each clusters. I have to show this in my React interface.
I would like to implement this in GraphQL but I don't know how to code this because I return 2 things in this request.

How can I write my request in GraphQL ?

Comment: Is this cypher inside a `@cypher` directive?

Comment: Hello, yes it is

Answer (score 1):

You are returning 2 values `c` and `articles` however there is no way to represent this in a GraphQL type. Make an intermediary type I will call mine `Intermediary`;

```
type CLUSTER {
   id: ID
}

type ARTICLE {
   id: ID
}

type Intermediary {
}
```

And embedded your `CLUSTER` and `ARTICLE` as fields on the type;

```
type Intermediary {
  cluster: CLUSTER 
  article: ARTICLE
}
```

Then use this type where your `@cypper` directive is;

```
type Query {
  myQuery: Intermediary @cypher(...)
}
```

When projecting the values out of your cypher query return an object representing your `Intermediary` type;

```
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)
WITH c
ORDER BY c.cluster_score DESC
LIMIT 5
MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_CLUSTER]-(a:ARTICLE)
WITH c,a
ORDER BY a.article_score  DESC
WITH c, collect(a)[..5] as articles
RETURN {
    cluster: c,
    articles: articles
}
```

Comment: Hello @DanStarns thank you, I'm going to try it.

Comment: Hello @DanStarns, I tried your code but I have an error I don't know what to do. Can I show you ?